# Adobe Illustrator: Setting order for text to be highlighted

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am trying to arrange my text in my Adobe Illustrator file such that when it is saved to pdf, and the reader wants to copy and paste the information in the document the order is somewhat preserved.

For example I have 2 main columns with multiple text boxes and I'd like to label it so that if the entire document is copied into a text file then it would read:

column1textbox1, 
column1textbox2, 
column1textbox3,
etc
column2textbox1, 
column2textbox2, 
column2textbox3,
etc

Right now it's all over the place

Answer (score 1):

InDesign has an export option called 'Create Tagged PDF' which does exactly what you need, but not sure this is available in Illustrator (not in CS6 at least):

- https://indesignsecrets.com/reasons-create-tagged-pdf.php
- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/structuring-pdfs.html

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to create the pdf with Illustrator then add the tags with InDesign? or would some of the structure get lost?

Comment: Never did that so can't say. Likely not going to work since ID will include AI content as outside links. Do a quick test, see what happens.